# hours minutes seconds to seconds ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, time

I want to convert time hours minutes seconds to seconds in ios. 
Is there any in built method for this?
How can I do this?

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *componentsDiff = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: from time to hrs, min seccs? or vice versa?

Comment: No I want current time in seconds

Comment: please explain more precisly: to seconds from rfeference date, since 1.1.1970 UTC , seconds since start of day? or what?

Comment: seconds since 1.1.1970 UTC, like unix time? (or java), or since apple reference date. You also should read the Apple Gudie on Date Formatting

Comment: Pretty sure he wants from start of day, hence the mention of converting hours minutes and seconds

Comment: You can use a calendar, you can use a date formatter, or you can simply say `seconds = (((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60) + seconds;`

Comment: start of date is nomralla not a good idea: start of day? UTC, local? That depens mor eon th eappliocation what he wants to with that seconds

Comment: If you want current time in seconds use `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]`

Comment: Yeah I want seconds since start of day

Comment: Check this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874049/time-difference-between-current-time-and-tweet-posted/13874590#13874590

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code for the insert date as a string and then return numbers of second.

```
- (NSNumber *)dateToSecondConvert:(NSString *)string {

    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    NSInteger hours   = [[components objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
    NSInteger minutes = [[components objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
    NSInteger seconds = [[components objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds];
}
```

May this help to lot.

Comment: Would be wrong twice a year if you live somewhere with Daylight Savings Time

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstand the question but this will give you current time in seconds from 1970

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]
```

Comment: As I understand the question (which is kinda hard), this is the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of examples, but this what you can do:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
//[comp hour]
//[comp minute]
//[comp second]
```