# Convert string to time (not date)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, time-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hours minutes seconds to seconds ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879328/hours-minutes-seconds-to-seconds-ios)

I have a time formatted as such

```
// format: HH:mm:ss,AAA
// example for 2 hours, 35 minutes, 15 seconds, and 207 milliseconds
02:35:15,207
```

I'm trying to convert that into seconds as a double. The above example would turn into:

```
// 2 hrs * 3600 + 25 min * 60 + 15.207
9315.207
```

I figure I can pick apart each element with a scanner, but I'm thinking there's probably an easier way. I tried using `NSDateFormatter` but I need this as a double, not as an `NSDate`. Any suggestions? Thanks.

***Further FYI***

This is for use with the `MPMoviePlayer` and the `currentTime` property is a double. For any given section where I have data to show, I am checking if `dataStartTime <= playerTime < dataEndTime`. So I'm using `double` because that's the type for `currentTime` already.

Comment: See this answer:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879328/hours-minutes-seconds-to-seconds-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, the idea is simple get two date one with your time and one with 00:00:00,000 time then take difference of their time.

```
- (double)secondsFromString:(NSString*)str {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"];
    NSString *dateString = @"1970-01-01";
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",dateString,str]];
    NSDate *refDate = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 00:00:00,000",dateString]];
    double time = [date timeIntervalSince1970] - [refDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    return time;
}
```